# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': "[object HTMLElement]" is not a valid custom element name

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, customization, domexception

Please help me I can't understand what the heck is causing the error. The code:-

```js
class button extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.style.cssText = 'display:block';
        button.textContent = super.textContent;
        shadow.appendChild(button);
    }
}
var Ω = (function () {

 'use strict';

 /**
  * Create the constructor
  * @param {String} selector The selector to use
  */
 var Constructor = function (selector) {
  if (!selector) return;
  if (selector === 'document') {
   this.elems = [document];
  } else if (selector === 'window') {
   this.elems = [window];
  } else {
   this.elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
 };

    /**
  * Run a callback on each item
  * @param  {Function} callback The callback function to run
  */
 Constructor.prototype.each = function (callback) {
  if (!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') return;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++) {
   callback(this.elems[i], i);
  }
  return this;
 };

 /**
  * 
  * @param  {String} className 
  */
 Constructor.prototype.register = function (className) {
  this.each(function (item) {
   customElements.define(item, className);
  });
  return this;
 };
    /**
  * Instantiate a new constructor
  */
 var instantiate = function (selector) {
  return new Constructor(selector);
 };

 /**
  * Return the constructor instantiation
  */
 return instantiate;

})();
Ω('lol-foo').register(button);
```

```html
<p>Expect a button down below</p>
<lol-foo>Hey</lol-foo>
```

It was thought that it will take the name from the first method(lol-foo here) and will add the class path and define it, but it seems that something wrong is written out and [object HTMLElement] is passed.

Your help will help [custags.js](https://obnoxiousnerd.github.io/custags.js/) help add a selector like jQuery($).
Answers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're providing a HTMLElement object to the first argument of `define()`, when it instead expects the custom element *name* as a string. For reference this name has to include a hyphen character, and be in lowercase. As such try this:

```
customElements.define(item.tagName.toLowerCase(), className);
```

Here's a working example:

```js
class button extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.style.cssText = 'display:block';
    button.textContent = super.textContent;
    shadow.appendChild(button);
  }
}
var Ω = (function() {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * Create the constructor
   * @param {String} selector The selector to use
   */
  var Constructor = function(selector) {
    if (!selector) return;
    if (selector === 'document') {
      this.elems = [document];
    } else if (selector === 'window') {
      this.elems = [window];
    } else {
      this.elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Run a callback on each item
   * @param  {Function} callback The callback function to run
   */
  Constructor.prototype.each = function(callback) {
    if (!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') return;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++) {
      callback(this.elems[i], i);
    }
    return this;
  };

  /**
   * 
   * @param  {String} className 
   */
  Constructor.prototype.register = function(className) {
    this.each(function(item) {
      customElements.define(item.tagName.toLowerCase(), className);
    });
    return this;
  };
  /**
   * Instantiate a new constructor
   */
  var instantiate = function(selector) {
    return new Constructor(selector);
  };

  /**
   * Return the constructor instantiation
   */
  return instantiate;
})();

Ω('lol-foo').register(button);
```

```html
<p>Expect a button down below</p>
<lol-foo>Hey</lol-foo>
```

It's also worth noting that the second argument of `define()` is the class constructor, so the argument name of `className` is a misnomer. Its value is correct in this example, though.

You can find more information on [`CustomElementRegistry.define()` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define)

Comment: could you help me in this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155479/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-define-on-customelementregistry-th