# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this constructor has already been used with this registry

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, customization, domexception

Here is the full code:-

```js
class code extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({
            mode: 'open'
          });
        const code = document.createElement('code');
        code.textContent = super.textContent;
        shadow.appendChild(code);
    }
}
var Ω = (function() {
    'use strict';
  
    /**
     * Create the constructor
     * @param {String} selector The selector to use
     */
    var Constructor = function(selector) {
      if (!selector) return;
      if (selector === 'document') {
        this.elems = [document];
      } else if (selector === 'window') {
        this.elems = [window];
      } else {
        this.elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      }
    };
  
    /**
     * Run a callback on each item
     * @param  {Function} callback The callback function to run
     */
    Constructor.prototype.each = function(callback) {
      if (!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') return;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++) {
        callback(this.elems[i], i);
      }
      return this;
    };
  
    
    Constructor.prototype.register = function(className) {
      this.each(function(item) {
        customElements.define(item.tagName.toLowerCase(), className);
      });
      return this;
    };

    Constructor.prototype.css = function(style){
        this.each(function(item) {
            item.style.cssText = style;
          });
          return this;
    }
    Constructor.prototype.value = function(){
        this.each(function(item) {
            const val = item.value;
            return val;
          });
          return this;
    }
    Constructor.prototype.load = function(fn){
        window.onload = fn;
        return fn;
    }
    /**
     * Instantiate a new constructor
     */
    var instantiate = function(selector) {
      return new Constructor(selector);
    };
  
    /**
     * Return the constructor instantiation
     */
    return instantiate;
  })();
  Ω('lol-bar').register(code);
Ω('check-1').register(code);
```

```html
<lol-bar>Hey</lol-bar><br />
<check-1>This should look like the above one</check-1>
```

I had expected that this will output both the tags lol-bar and check-1 the same format but this thingy says indirectly that I'm allowed to use a constructor only once and hence further definitions can't get into reality. Someone please solve this and get me outta this paradox.
Help and answers appreciated. Would greatly help in development of [custags.js](https://obnoxiousnerd.github.io/custags.js), an open source project of mine.

Comment: The error is because you can't use the same constructor for multiple customElements. If you want to work around that, copy+paste+rename it, although it's rather redundant.

Comment: Any other alternative to your solution, 'cause a user of my framework can't do this

Comment: Frankly, it's a code smell. Why do you have two elements which need the same constructor to do the same thing? If that's the case you don't need two customer elements, but just one.

Comment: hmmm... thats one. But what if two modules need different elements using the same constructor? How can I do that? Any ideas? No copy paste